# How to prevent re-rendering of components that have not changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a component that consists of several other components such as text fields, and when an input is made to the text field, all other components are re-rendered.

I would like to prevent the re-rendering and only re-render the component that actually changes.

I have seen that `useCallback` is the right way to do this and I have already seen how to use it. However, I'm having some trouble getting `useCallBack` to work correctly for my case.

Even if I set it up in a simple manner as below, each new character entered into the text field causes the button to be rendered again.

I don't see my mistake.

[See working example in sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-meadow-1dkxw?file=/src/App.js)

```
const Button = () => {
  console.log("Button Rendered!");
  window.alert("Button Rendered");
  return <button onClick="">Press me</button>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState("Hallo");

  const onChangeInput = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      setTextInput(e.target.value);
    },
    [textInput]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={onChangeInput}
        value={textInput}
      />
      <Button />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just create another component and store the state with this.

Comment: **There is nothing wrong with this.** Perfectly normal React code, and React is doing its job with the virtualDOM to determine what should actually change in the real DOM, and in the case of `Button` - nothing. Its re-renders result into no DOM changes, and it is also very cheap to call again and again to such a simple component with that probably has little to no internal logic.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Personally I would avoid `React.memo` / `React.useRef` / `React.useCallback`.

The simplest solution to your example is just create another component, and store the state with this.

eg.

```
const Button = () => {
  console.log("Button Rendered!");
  window.alert("Button Rendered");
  return <button onClick="">Press me</button>;
};

const TextInput = () => {
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState("Hallo");
  const onChangeInput = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      setTextInput(e.target.value);
    },
    [textInput]
  );
  return (
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={onChangeInput}
        value={textInput}
      />
  );
}


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <TextInput/>
      <Button />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the above if you change Text, there is not State change in App, so Button doesn't get re-rendered, no need for useMemo etc..

You will find React works really well, the more you divide your components up, not only does it solve issues of re-render, but potentially makes it a lot easier to re-use components later.

IOW: keep state as close to the component as possible, and performance will follow.

Of course your example is simple, and in a real app you will have HOC's etc to cope with, but that's another question.. :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it gave me the understanding I needed, especially regarding the drawbacks of memo. However, I am now wondering how to prevent rerendering in components that contain more than one subcomponent. See the modified example here in SandBox. In the example, as soon as the parent component saves the input in the state, the button is rerenderd again. [Sandbox] (https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-smoke-8uzh3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @dan_boy  Yes, that's the part I mention about HOC's.  Again the principle would be the same,  keep the state where it's needed.  Placing a setState in App is going to cause a re-render to all it's children.  To prevent this what most people do with React is use a more robust state management,  Redux is a popular choice.   But that's not the only option, and I personally use my own based on proxy's.  It might be an idea to post another question on this.

Comment: After wasting an hour on finding the solution on web, finally stumbled on your answer and it really helped me understand whats going on and how can I optimize the code. Really appreciate it

Comment: Brilliant!!!!!!

Comment: I learned new thing about react today , thanks!

Comment: Incorrect. The state should remain on the parent almost always, and never on the text field itself, because almost always it is wished to do something with the state (the text field value) and if that state is locked within the `<TextInput/` it won't be accessible. Your example makes no sense, because there is no point making a controlled input here if the state is never used inside or outside.

Comment: @vsync  This is a simple example, and if you read my answers in more detail you will see that I personally DONT store state with the component.  And VDOM to DOM compare's do come with a cost, for something as small as this, yes, it's hardly going to make much difference, but for a page with 100's of controls it does.  React's internal state is pretty much useless for component to component state management anyway, and is the reason I also mentioned that in my answer (comments).  So no, the answer is not incorrect..

Comment: `memo` is actually the preferred way here, and moreover when no props exists. Also *"keep state as close to the component as possible"* is not so good of an advice as it depends on the situation, and does not apply to the majority of them. Sometimes the state is global, sometimes it's in a React `context` Object, or at some ancestor's level, and that's OK, as long as **you know what you're doing**, you can eliminate needless rendering no matter where the state is. Problem is, most people don't really understand React and 99% of the time I see performance-related of bad code.

Comment: @vsync  We are talking about 2 types of state here,  `useState` I would say is pretty much a private state, once you require more it's a pretty bad idea to fudge `useContext` or passing props down the tree, as it get very messy very quickly.  And again is the reason anything more complex than a single component should really be using a proper state manager, even React dev's created one for this reason. ->  https://recoiljs.org/  , `useMemo` certainly has it's place, but remember it will still requires the VDOM compare and that can be expensive, main reason why solidJS is so much faster.

Comment: BTW - `Recoil` was a disaster, this is why [Jotai](https://jotai.org/) was created.
Why are you talking about `useMemo`? We are talking about `memo` here. It does not do any VDOM comparison and is cheap & fast, exactly for such situations as OP's. I would also refrain from saying `useState` should be private. Many times a setter is sent as a prop to a child, it's a common and good practice, when the state is to be shared with both parent & child.

Comment: @vsync because that's what I assumed you were talking about, so your on about `React.memo`, fair enough, but use wisely,. And anyway, if you use state correctly like I've been saying from the start, you don't need to use the `React.memo`,  if your having performance issues without using it, I would say your doing something wrong.  `Jotai -> inspired by Recoil`,  Yeah, it must have been a massive disaster..  BTW: I don't use Recoil, I mentioned it to point out the shortfalls of `useState`..

Comment: @vsync  Also worth noting, from that Jotai link -> `and eliminates the need for the memoization technique.`   Exactly the point I'm making.  Anyway, thanks for pointing out Jotai, it looks a good state manager, worth keeping an eye on, certainly better than the good practice (opinion based) `React.memo`.  :)

Comment: Already-existing complex system cannot easily (or at all) introduce packages such as *Jotai* to their codebase, as refactoring to hundreds or components would be required, and likely, not feasible, and so resorting to immediately-available solutions such as `React.memo` or other ways (such as my [react-ref-watcher](https://github.com/yairEO/react-ref-watcher/) which eliminates useless re-renders when parent state changes) are not so-bad solutions.

Comment: @vsync  Agree with you there, personally I find React without a state manager very limited, but if you have a small component and want to prevent re-renders, and not require another external lib, `React.memo` would then be very handy.

Answer (score 19):

`useCallback` does not prevent rerenders. `React.memo` is what prevents renders. It does a shallow comparison of the previous props with the new props, and if they're the same, it skips rendering:

```
const Button = React.memo(() => {
  console.log("Button Rendered!");
  window.alert("Button Rendered");
  return <button onClick="">Press me</button>;
});
```

The only role that useCallback plays in this is that sometimes you want to pass a function as a prop to a memoized component. For the memoization to work, props need to not change, and useCallback can help the props to not change.

Answer (score 2):

changing the state causes re-render component along with all his heirs, to prevent re-render some sections, you can use useMemo to prevent unwanted re-rendering...

NOTE: useMemo has some costs... so don't overuse it (**In this small example, it is not recommended at all**).

in this case, if you do not need to re-rendering, you can use the useRef to save the input reference to get that value whenever you need it.

e.g:

```
const BlahBlah = () => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef(undefined);

  return (
    <div>
        <input ref={inputRef} />
        <button onClick={() => console.log(inputRef.current.value)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. I wanted to avoid rendering a component which dependent on part2 of state, when only part1 has changed.

I used `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` as described here https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html to avoid rendering it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it this way:

```
const [state_data, set_state_data] = useState([
    true, // loading.
    {}, // vehicle.
    {} // user.
]);
```

This allows rendering only 1x instead of 3x and React keeps track of the changes. For some reason it won't track the change of objects, but arrays yes.

Comment: This seems to me a deprecated approach, can you show how you update your state!