# React Hooks: how to avoid re-rendering of component on another state change?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Here is my code.

```
const test = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(0)
    const clickOne = () => setState(1)
    const clickTwo = () => setState(2)

    return (
        <>
        <div className="title">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="buttons">
            <button onClick={clickOne}>1</button>
            <button onClick={clickTwo}>2</button>
        </div>
        <div className="content">
            {state === 0 ? <div>click!</div> : state === 1 ? <div>1</div> : <div> 2 </div>}
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

What I'm trying here is to **only** re-render "#buttons" area and "#content" area when `<button>` in "#buttons" area is clicked.

As of now, "#title" area is re-rendered every time the button is clicked. **How can I force "#title" area not to be re-rendered?** Thanks.

Comment: It is a repetitive question, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590082/how-to-prevent-re-rendering-of-components-that-have-not-changed)

Comment: Why are you concerned about the `title` re-rendering?

Comment: @Joshua I was wondering if I could optimize rendering of the compoonents.

Comment: There's no need to for you to be concerned about micro optimisations. Most especially on something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use different components and React.memo

```
const Header = React.memo(() => {
  return (<div className="title">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>)
});

const test = () => {
const [state, setState] = useState(0)
const clickOne = () => setState(1)
const clickTwo = () => setState(2)

return (
    <>
    <Header/>
    <div className="buttons">
        <button onClick={clickOne}>1</button>
        <button onClick={clickTwo}>2</button>
    </div>
    <div className="content">
        {state === 0 ? <div>click!</div> : state === 1 ? <div>1</div> : <div> 2 </div>}
    </div>
    </>
)
}
```

From the docs:

> If your component renders the same result given the same props, you
> can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some
> cases by memoizing the result.

But note that you can't use it to rely on the render prevention, rather it's just optimization

Answer (score 0):

You should split `"#title` into a component.

```
const Title = () => {
  return (
    <div className="title">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const Test = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const clickOne = () => setState(1);
  const clickTwo = () => setState(2);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="buttons">
        <button onClick={clickOne}>1</button>
        <button onClick={clickTwo}>2</button>
      </div>
      <div className="content">
        {state === 0 ? <div>click!</div> : state === 1 ? <div>1</div> : <div> 2 </div>}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

And using it in the parent component

```
<Title />
<Test />
```