# How can I prevent re-render after state changed in React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to build an app but the problem is when I change a state, all the components re-render.

```
const App=()=>{
   const [showMenu,setshowMenu]=useState(false)
   

 return(
     <>

     <Header showMenu={showMenu} setShowMenu={setShowMenu}/>

     <MainArea/>

     {showMenu ? <Menu/> : null}

     <Footer/>

    </>
 )

}
```

When I set showMenu to true by button, a menu appears but the problem is all my components (Header,MainArea,Footer) do re-render. I don't want that. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### You can use [useMemo](https://dev.to/afozbek/react-hooks-usememo-4n23) hook.

*It prevents specific jsx contents from rerendering, even when the state that those jsx contents/components use get updated.*

---

```
const App=()=>{
// you can only memoize parts that do not require use of the updated variable in this case. It means that Header cannot be memoized.

const mainArea = React.useMemo( () => <MainArea/>, [] );

const footer = React.useMemo( () => <Footer/>, [] );

   const [showMenu,setShowMenu]=useState(false)
   

 return(
     <>

     <Header showMenu={showMenu} setShowMenu={setShowMenu}/>

     {mainArea}

     {showMenu ? <Menu/> : null}

     {footer}

    </>
 )

}
```

---

### EDIT:

Does the  really need the state of the **showMenu**? Or we can only pass the **setShowMenu** to it?
If so, then you can also memoize the Header component into memo chunk like:

const header = React.useMemo( () => , [] );

Comment: Thank you very much. That is what I was looking for. I use showMenu variable in header to set opposite of boolen value. (setShowMenu(!showMenu))

Comment: @CD, you can remove passing showMenu prop, and instead do it like setShowMenu( currValue => !currValue )
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/iarjb5/in_usestate_setter_function_when_to_pass_a/

Then you can memoize the <Header/> too! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [React memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) (or [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) if you use classes) on the components that you don't want to re-render (MainArea,Footer). This way when an update is forced by their parent they will first make a check if any of their `props` changed and if not (which is your case), re-render will be skipped.

However it's advisable to perform memoization on *expensive* components only instead of wrapping everything with `React.memo`, because memoization also introduces some overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, whenever state changes, the component re-renders. You can only make some specific components to no re-render when state change occurs using `useMemo`.

If you need to store information, without the information causing any re-renders, you can use `useRef`.
Like state, refs are retained by React between re-renders. However, setting state re-renders a component. Changing a ref does not! You can access the current value of that ref through the `ref.current` property.

```
export default function Counter() {
  let ref = useRef(0);

  function handleClick() {
    ref.current = ref.current + 1;
    alert('You clicked ' + ref.current + ' times!');
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me!
    </button>
  );
}
```

Clicking on the button `Click me!` does not trigger any re-renders, while updating the information inside the ref.

reference: https://react.dev/learn/escape-hatches

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the state is only for header component. U can bring the state inside the Header component. U can read here for further explaination https://overreacted.io/before-you-memo/

Also here another good explanation [How to prevent re-rendering of components that have not changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590082/how-to-prevent-re-rendering-of-components-that-have-not-changed)

Answer (score -2):

To prevent re-rendering of reusable component while changing other states, We can use **React.memo()**

```
const MainArea = React.useMemo(() => {
return <div />;
});
const Footer = React.useMemo(() => {
   return <div />;
});
const App = () => {
   const [showMenu,setshowMenu]=useState(false)

   return(
      <>
      <Header showMenu={showMenu} setShowMenu={setShowMenu}/>
      <MainArea/>
      {showMenu ? <Menu/> : null}
      <Footer/>
      </>
  )
}
```

Comment: [Mila said that already; over a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69966187/19068).