# Nextjs Memorizing the pages to prevent re-rendring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my Next.js app, I have two pages, where each page sets a random person name when the component is loaded for the first time.

**simpsons.tsx**

```
export default function Simpsons() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState<string>();
  useEffect(() => {
    const persons = ["Homer", "Marge", "Lisa", "Bart", "Maggie"];

    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * persons.length);
    setPerson(persons[random]);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{person} simpson</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**friends.tsx**

```
export default function Friends() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState<string>();
  useEffect(() => {
    const persons = ["Ross", "Monica", "Racheal", "Joey", "Phebee","Chandler"];

    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * persons.length);
    setPerson(persons[random]);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My friend {person}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My _app.tsx file is wrapped with a layout component and I switch the pages using the navbar in the layout component. When I go to the friends' page and then come back to the Simpsons page, previously selected Simpson should be there. (**COMPONENT SHOULD NOT RE-RENDER EVERY TIME I SWITCH THE PAGES**)

For this simple use case, we can use the state management solution like context. But my goal is not to keep state, persist. My goal is to prevent the re-renderings.

How can I achieve this using Next.js?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590082/how-to-prevent-re-rendering-of-components-that-have-not-changed

Answer (score 0):

Navigating from one page to another causes the first page component to un-mount and second page to mount. *Navigating back to first page using next router does the same thing.*

```
 useEffect(() => {
const persons = ["Homer", "Marge", "Lisa", "Bart", "Maggie"];

const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * persons.length);
setPerson(persons[random]);
}, []);
```

Ideally to handle such scenarios, it is best advised to decouple this logic from page mount/unmount function.