# Sending React State to PayPal Hosted Fields

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I'm currently re-rendering the hosted fields every time the card_name state changes. For some reason I cannot access any react state information inside the hosted fields. Is there a way to send the react state so that I can access it inside the window functions?

```
const [card_name, setCardName] = useState('')

        window.paypal.HostedFields.render({
             // Call your server to set up the transaction
             createOrder: function () {
                console.log(card_name)
               
             },
        })
```

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but have you tried using the `@paypal/react-paypal-js` sample as a basis? https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/paypal-paypalhostedfields--default

Comment: Well actually thats the reason I switched over. I thought there might be a hacky way to use the PayPalScript Provider along with the window functions to achieve certain results. It seems that is not the case and the hosted fields must re-render every time the state changes, clearing the fields.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to accomplish you might need to split the state out into another component https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590082/how-to-prevent-re-rendering-of-components-that-have-not-changed , or use a state manager like Redux or hooks, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html