# how to avoid a component being re-render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

how to avoid re-render a child component , I've tested use memo hook it did not work with me can you please help and correct my code .

here is my code

Home Component :

```
function Home({todos, todoFun }) {

const [ increment ,setIncrement] = useState(1);
const [data , setData] = useState(['test']);
  

      const v = 'some text';


      const addValue = () =>{
          
        setData( (data) => [...data, v ]);
      }

      useMemo(() => data , [data]);

  return (
      <div>
               <h1>{increment}</h1>
                     <Todos todos ={data}  todoFun={addValue}/>
                <br />
                    <button onClick={() => setIncrement(increment => increment + 1)} style={{pading: "20px"}}>
                              Increment
                    </button>
      </div>
  )
}
```

and from Todos component :

```
function Index({todos, todoFun }) {


  return (
    <div>
      {console.log('hello from child ')}
        {todos.map((todo, index ) =>
        {

          return <p key={index}>{todo}</p>;
        }
        )}
        <button onClick={todoFun}>Add Text</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default memo(Index);
```

it keep displaying hello from child , when clicking on both buttons

Comment: First of all why do you wan't to prevent the component to rerender? it appears that your component is dependent on the `data` prop, and apperntly on your button click, you are updating your data state which will reflects the change to your todos component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent re-rendering of components that have not changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590082/how-to-prevent-re-rendering-of-components-that-have-not-changed)

Comment: @Amr when I click on Increment button it should not re-render child component(todos)

Comment: Why is this an issue?

Comment: If you don't want it to re-render then don't use a state...

Comment: @salmanaacvf when you click on the increment btn it sets the state `setData`, setting the state will trigger rerendering, and in your code you are passing the data as prop to the todos component, the component **todos** has to be definitely rerendered because you are mapping over the data state.

Answer (score 0):

that is how I solved the issue thanks to @Liam's comment , editing add value function :

```
 const addValue = useCallback((e)=>{
          
        setData( (data) => [...data, v ]);
      }, [data])
```

Comment: without data dependency also it'll work.

Comment: Yes true @Rahul Shama it worked without dependency