# How to show and hide only one element in map() function?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a project in Expo React Native where I use the map function to render elements with data. One of the elements is a photo that needs to be displayed only when the button is pressed.

I tried this but it shows and hides all the photos.

```
const [showPhoto, setShowPhoto] = useState(false);
//...
{readings.map(
                (
                    {
                        metersID,
                        id,
                        date,
                        volume,
                        type,
                    },
                    i
                ) => { return (
//...some elements before this
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowPhoto(!showPhoto)}>
                                <FontAwesome name="photo" size={40} color="black" />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            {showPhoto ? (
                                <ImageViewer
                                    placeholderImageSource=""
                                    selectedImage={readings[i].photo}
                                />
                            ) : null}
//...some elements after this
```

Comment: Just create another component, you will also then have some extra rendering performance -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590082/how-to-prevent-re-rendering-of-components-that-have-not-changed/66590428#66590428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an array of booleans to track the visibility of each photo individually. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
const [showPhotos, setShowPhotos] = useState(Array(readings.length).fill(false));

// ...

{readings.map(({ metersID, id, date, volume, type }, i) => (
    // ... some elements before this

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => togglePhotoVisibility(i)}>
        <FontAwesome name="photo" size={40} color="black" />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    {showPhotos[i] ? (
        <ImageViewer
            placeholderImageSource=""
            selectedImage={readings[i].photo}
        />
    ) : null}

    // ... some elements after this
))}

// ...

function togglePhotoVisibility(index) {
    setShowPhotos(prevShowPhotos => {
        const newShowPhotos = [...prevShowPhotos];
        newShowPhotos[index] = !newShowPhotos[index];
        return newShowPhotos;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, but I changed it to `const [showPhoto, setShowPhoto] = useState([]);` and add `setShowPhoto(Array(_array.length).fill(false));` to my useEffect func. Because I had an error "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render" with your code.